# Is this true that the sequences evenly sampled from functions in $L^p$ are in $l_p$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Is the following statement true ?

> Given a function $f(x)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $1\le p<\infty$, the sequence $\{f(x+kT)\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is in $l_p$ for any $x$ and $T$ if every number in the sequence is finite.

Comment: $L_p$ consists of equivalence classes of a.e. equal functions...

Comment: No, "taking a sample" is unbounded operator in $L_p$.

Comment: @user251257 True but what does this imply ?

Comment: @A.G. Maybe I can add some mild conditions, e.g., continuous function in $L_p$ ?

Comment: @Hua It does not help. You may need $L_p$ bound on the derivative too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I studied functional analysis with bounded operators only. Not familiar with unbounded operators now. I need some time to understand your tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is not true for *every* $x\in\mathbb{R}$, however it is true for *almost every* $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

Suppose that there is a measurable $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathrm{Leb}(E)>0$ such that $(f(x+kT))_{k}\notin\ell^p$ for all $x\in E$. W.l.o.g. assume that $E\cap (T+E)=\emptyset$. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^p\,dx\geq \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int_{kT+E}|f(x)|^p\,dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int_E|f(x-kT)|^p\,dx=\int_E\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|f(x-kT)|^p\,dx=\infty
$$
contradiciting the assumption $f\in L^p$.

Comment: Why could you exchange the sum and integral in the second equality ?

Comment: That's an application of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Er, as far as I know, Fubini theorem applies when the two iterated integrals are bounded. But here you are suggesting they are not bounded. I don't think the theorem can apply here.

Comment: There's also a version of Fubini's theorem for non-negative integrands (wikipedia calls it "Tonelli's theorem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions).