# Proof that $[f,g](\xi):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(\xi+2\pi k)\overline{g(\xi+2\pi k)}$ is $L_1((-\pi,\pi])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading a note which states that

> $[f,g](\xi):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(\xi+2\pi k)\overline{g(\xi+2\pi k)}$ are $L_1((-\pi,\pi])$ if $f$ and $g$ is in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$.

To prove it, I think the first step is to guarantee the series on the right-hand size converges **almost everywhere**. I haven't worked out this step:-(

But if I assume it converges a.e. The following is how I argue that the $[f,g]$ is $L_1$. A well-known result is if $f$ and $g$ is $L_2$ then $fg$ is $L_1$. So $f\overline{g}$ is $L_1$. Since $L_1$ is a vector space, $\sum_{|k|\lt N}f(\xi+2\pi k)\overline{g(\xi+2\pi k)}$ is $L_1$. By the completeness of $L_1$, it arrives that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(\xi+2\pi k)\overline{g(\xi+2\pi k)}$ is $L_1$ if the limit exists. So $[f,g]$ is $L_1$ if I can prove the first step.

My question is how to prove the first step, and whether the argument above is OK.

Update: I think my argument of the second step is totally wrong.

**New Update on Feb 17th, 2017, proof by Poisson summation formula**

By Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, we know $f\overline{g}$ is $L_1(\mathbb{R})$. According to the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), we get

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(f\overline{g})(\xi+2\pi k)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f(\xi+2\pi k)\overline{g(\xi+2\pi k)}$$ **converges almost everywhere**, i.e., 
$$[f,g](\xi)<\infty$$
for a.e. $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $[f,g](\xi)$ is $L_1((-\pi,\pi])$ because it is finite a.e. and $(-\pi,\pi]$ is a bounded domain.

New new update: embarrassing that the new update above is wrong:-(

Comment: If the limits exists in $L^1$, it's vacuus to say that it is in $L^1$ (and has nothing to do with completeness). If the limit exists only a.e., it does not follow automatically that it is in $L^1$ (take your favorite measurable function not in $L^1$ and approximate it a.e. by step functions).

Comment: @user1952009 Is your exchange of sum and integral in the last step guaranteed by Fubini' theorem, because the integrand $|f(x+k)g(x+k)|$ is nonegative ? And if $[f,g](\xi)$ is proved $L_1((-\pi,\pi])$, then it converges almost everywhere in $(-\pi,\pi]$. Right ?

Comment: @user1952009 I mean you change the sum over $\mathbb{Z}$ inside integral over $[0,1]$, to get $\int_0^1 h(x)$. Right ?

Comment: The Poisson formula is allowed if and only if both side converge. You didn't prove the RHS converges

Comment: @user1952009 It seems that you are right. I need to check that. Anyway, I suddenly realized that if we proved that $[f,g](\xi)$ is $L_1((-\pi,\pi])$, then it is necessarily finite a.e. on $(-\pi,\pi]$, hence finite a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$, isn't it ? That means the series converges point-wisely a.e. ?

Comment: Since $h(x) = x^{-1/2}1_{|x| < 1}$ is in $L^1$ then $\sum_{n,k} \frac{h(x - n/k)}{2^n 2^k}$ is in $L^1$ and it has a singularity at every $x$ rational. The convergence in $L^1$ norm is much easier to handle !

Comment: @user1952009 But rational points is of measure zero, right ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm showing why pointwise convergence isn't adapted to $L^p$ spaces. And $\frac{1_{x \in (0,1]}}{x}$ is finite a.e. but it is not in $L^1([0,1])$ so the last sentence of your post isn't correct.

Comment: @user1952009 Oh, I see, thanks for pointing this out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since $|f|,|g| \in L^2$, by Cauchy-Schwarz $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)g(x)|dx = \langle |f|,|g| \rangle \le \|f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2}$$ so that $fg \in L^1$
- By definition $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)g(x)|dx = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_k^{k+1} |f(x)g(x)|dx = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_0^1 |f(x+k)g(x+k)|dx$$ so that $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z},|k| > m} \int_0^1 |f(x+k)g(x+k)|dx$ converges and $\to 0$ as $m \to \infty$.
- The last step is letting $h_n(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^n f(x+k)g(x+k)$, with $m < n$ you have $$\|h_n-h_m\|_{L^1([0,1])} =  \int_0^1 |\sum_{m<|k|\le n}f(x+k)g(x+k)|dx  $$ $$\le\sum_{m<|k|\le n} \int_0^1 |f(x+k)g(x+k)|dx \le\sum_{|k|> m} \int_0^1 |f(x+k)g(x+k)|dx$$ so that $\|h_n-h_m\|_{L^1([0,1])} \to 0$ as $n > m \to \infty$ and $h_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1([0,1])$.
- Hence the limit $h(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(x)$ is in $L^1([0,1])$

Comment: Then this proof avoids to prove the point-wise convergence.

Comment: @Hua yes, looking at the pointwise convergence should be more complicated, you'll need probably one or two theorems

Comment: @Hua and the last line is unclear, I meant $h = \lim_{n \to \infty} h_n$ converges in the $L^1([0,1])$ sense

Comment: Thanks for this proof. Yes. $L_1$ convergence only implies point-wise convergence of a subsequence. I'll continue to see the point-wise part.

Comment: Hi, would you mind taking a look at the sketchy proof I added in the post ? I used the Poisson summation formula to get **point-wise convergence a.e.** to guarantee $[f,g](\xi)$ is well-defined a.e. Then naturally it is integrable on a bounded domain $(-\pi,\pi]$. Do you think is it OK ?

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not true as stated.

Let $f\in L^2$. By my answer to your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966625/is-this-true-that-the-sequences-evenly-sampled-from-functions-in-lp-are-in-lp), $[f,f](\xi)$ exists for almost all $\xi\in \mathbb{R}$. However, $[f,f]$ is not in $L^1$:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}[f,f](\xi)\,d\xi=\int_{\mathbb R}\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|f(\xi+2\pi k)|^2\,d\xi=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int_{\mathbb R}|f(\xi+2\pi k)|^2\,d\xi=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi=\infty.
$$

Comment: I think the exchange of the sum and integration in the second equality needs further verification.

Comment: I guess I made a mistake in posting this question. It should be $L_1((-\pi,\pi])$.

Comment: @MaoWao. Could you point out why you think the statement is not true? I am quite sure it is correct.

Comment: @jvnv MaoWao proved the original problem with $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ which is not correct. My mistake.

Comment: @Hua. Thanks for clearing this up. As I had a solution along the same lines as MaoWao, I have just placed an answer.

Comment: @jvnv Thanks for the modified proof. I think MaoWao should get part of the credits :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following proof is different from the one outlined in your question. It is primarily based on results of measure and integration theory, and it does not use the completeness of $L^1$ explicitly.

Let $f, g \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$. Then
$$ \int_{[-\pi, \pi]} \bigg| [f,g](\xi)\bigg| \; d\xi \leq \int_{[-\pi, \pi]}  \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} | f(\xi + 2\pi k) g (\xi + 2\pi k) |\; d\xi ,  $$
and by Beppo-Levi's theorem, 
$$ \int_{[-\pi, \pi]}  \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} | f(\xi + 2\pi k) g (\xi + 2\pi k) |\; d\xi  = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{[-\pi, \pi]}  | f(\xi + 2\pi k) g (\xi + 2\pi k) |\; d\xi.  $$
Noting now that $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} [-k, k]$ and a change of variable yields
$$ \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{[-\pi, \pi]}  | f(\xi + 2\pi k) g (\xi + 2\pi k) | \;d\mu(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} | f(\xi) g (\xi) | \;d\xi < \infty,$$
which is what had to be shown.

Comment: I never saw this notation $[f,g](\xi) = \sum_k f(\xi+2\pi k) \overline{g(\xi+2\pi k)}$, and most people know Beppo-Levi as the monotone convergence theorem (or MCT)

Comment: The notation is defined in OP's question.

Comment: Yes no problem. I meant I needed time for understanding your answer. And I don't get the point of $d\mu(\xi)$, in this context it suggests we are integrating with respect to an arbitrary measure (not the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: I see your point regarding the measure. I simply always use $d\mu$ in the context of integration, which in this particular case simply denotes the Lebesgue measure. I will edit my answer in this regard to make it more consistent with the notation of OP's question.

Comment: I think in the context of $L^p$ spaces, you can  use the Riemann integral notation, and if someone asks, you say it is a Darboux or a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, or a notation for Lebesgue's.

Comment: @user1952009 For your information, this notation $[f,g]$ is used in wavelet analysis, e.g., in [page 14,  this note](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=3E6936501DB4DB4A8A3CB39C9BBE1075?doi=10.1.1.361.3765&rep=rep1&type=pdf). There it is claimed that $[f,g](\xi)$ is finite almost everywhere

Comment: It is not merely used as a notation. In fact, the map $[\cdot, \cdot] : L^2 \times L^2 \to L^1$ is an object studied for the sake of itself. It possess interesting relations with $C^*$-algebras. See the paper *Bracket Products for Weyl-Heisenberg Frames* by Casazza & Lammers.

Comment: @jvnv Oh, great! thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know that

Comment: @jvnv Hi, would you mind taking a look at the sketchy proof I added in my post ? I found the Poisson summation formula is closely connected to the definition of $[f,g]$ and it seems that the formula gives us the **point-wise convergence a.e.** to gurantee $[f,g](\xi)$ is well-defined a.e.

Comment: @Hua. Poisson's summation *formula* provides an identity between a function and its Fourier transform. In order to make sense of such an identity, it should of course be well-defined. The well-definedness is shown by the arguments I have given above. The well-definedness is *not* Poisson's summation formula, but just assures that this formula makes sense. The phrasing of the theorem on the link you provide is a bit strange. The well-definedness should not really be part of the statement of the theorem in my opinion.

Comment: @jvnv Yes, finally I realized that you just proved the Poisson summation formula for $L_1(\mathbb{R})$. You may be interested in this paper, for [Lemma 1.1](https://www.uni-hohenheim.de/~gzim/Publications/sm.pdf)

Comment: @Hua. I definitely did not prove Poisson's summation formula. I only proved that one of the series occuring in this formula is well-defined.

Comment: @jvnv Yes, I see.